# Cannot Connect to RDP from Laptop on Ethernet, WiFi and Phone are OK?

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

**What I can do:**

- can connect to desktop Win10pro from phone (wifi/data)
- can connect to desktop Win10pro from laptop Win10pro (wifi only)
- can connect to desktop Win10pro from work Win7 (desktop)
- can connect to desktop Win10pro from TeamViewer

**Problem:**

When I try to connect to my desktop from my laptop using the usb ethernet dongle, everything listed above seizes to function; only a black screen after logging in. Keep in mind, this setup did work 5 months ago, only thing that changed was that I reset/refresh my laptop because it became bogged down and switched from college to home.

**What I've tried:**

- System Restore on the host desktop
- sfc /scannow both host and laptop
- resetting network adapter and settings on laptop
- checking regedit to make sure 3389 was listening on laptop
- disabled/enabled NLA
- disabled/enabled RDP on host desktop
- enabled RDP on latop
- uninstalled network adapter and reinstalled on laptop
- turning off wifi on laptop and then trying to connect

If anyone has any other suggestions, that would be awesome.

UPDATE: As someone suggest to get a new USB Dongle, went out and bought one. Still does not work. Extremely laggy and black boxes everywhere.

Comment: Sounds like your USB dongle (or drivers) is dropping packets :) Have you tried with a new USB dongle?

Comment: No. I highly doubt it is the dongle as I am able to game/browse the internet with it with 0 packet loss (maybe ~1% if I leave ping www.google.com -t going for a while)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What solved my issue was using the internal ipv4 address when I am on the local network; else, using the external ipv4 when I am away from home.

Thing to note is that even when I was internally using ipv6, I had a huge issue with this and could not connect to it internally using external ipv4 with :3389 at the end of it.

Hope this helps someone.